How to perform a DNS query to a specific DNS server from PHP
So, basically, I need the PHP equivalent of the following DNS queries:
dig @dns.google yahoo.com A
dig @8.8.8.8 yahoo.com A
but to run them from PHP.
Thanks for all the suggestions.

You can run command-line executables from PHP very easily with shell_exec, or several other similar functions.
